# How to connect DVD SATA writers to write from one to another

Tags: windows

My question is in the title. Can the cables be the problem? Also can someone list me some of the best DVD writers? Where do I connect DVD writer cables on my motherboard and where hard disk?

Comment: You don't connect them together, they are just simple SATA devices. Each one would have power from the power supply and a SATA cable connection to a SATA port on the motherboard. Where you connect them to would vary based on your mainboard. Typically, the HDD would go on SATA 0 (or 1, depending on how the numbering starts), and the optical drives on any ports after that. People have different preferences, for example mine has 8 SATA ports, the optical drive is on 7 because i have an external HDD docking bay on 8, but in general it doesn't matter after the first HDD.

Comment: As far as "best DVD writers", we do not make hardware recommendations here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write directly from one writer to the other, you need to connect both of them to your motherboard.

SATA DVD writers, like SATA disks, need a SATA host to issue commands. They won't magically start reading a disk and transmitting the content to the other without a command to do so. Even if they would, how would they know which one is supposed to read and which one is supposed to write. You may find enclosures that can function as a SATA host for multiple writers, but unless you plan to do a lot of copying, it would be a waste of money. Any modern PC should be able to handle reading and writing to DVD without a problem while doing other tasks.

Where you connect your SATA DVD writers to the motherboard doesn't really matter. Any somewhat current BIOS will recognize SATA disks and SATA optical drives and have options to boot from them no matter which port you use. The BIOS should also have an option to select the SATA disk you want to boot from in case you have more than one. You should also have received a manual with your motherboard. If you don't have it, you can probably find it online at the vendor's website.